# TextWatcher - Increase value of last char by one

Tags: android, textwatcher

What I am trying to do is this: User enters text in an edittext. Example: "ab" then when he enters a character like '<' let's say, that would cause the last char typed before that to be increased by one. In this example, it'd do "ac" ('<' should be deleted too). On onTextChanged method, I use:

```
    if (s.length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 1) == '<') { //ab<
        character = s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 2); //keep b

        current_string = s.toString().substring(0, (s.length() - 2)); //a
        et.setText(current_string); //set a
        next_character_to_integer = (int) character + 1; //b is 98 ascii, need 99
        integer_to_character = (char) next_character_to_integer; // 99 = char c
        et.setText(s + String.valueOf(integer_to_character)); //set a+c
        length = s.length();
        et.setSelection(length); //move cursor after c

    }
```

But this gives "abqc"!!! I might be close enough but still can't find the solution. Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (s.length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 1) == '<') {

    character = s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 2); 
    current_string = s.toString().substring(0, (s.length() - 2));          
    character += 1;
    et.setText(current_string + character);
    length = et.getText().toString().length();
    et.setSelection(length);

}
```

This should work.

Comment: can you see what exception you are getting in the Logcat ? also, i've made an edit, please try the new edited code ...

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (3 ... 3) ends beyond length 2

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
et.setText(s + String.valueOf(integer_to_character)); //set a+c
```

you are using the original value of `s` which you have not updated.  Change the line to:

```
et.setText(current_string + String.valueOf(integer_to_character)); //set a+c
```

and see what you get.

Comment: thanks for your help. tried this and it causes app to stop working T_T

Comment: with what error message?  You will also need to change the setting of `length`, as the new string that is populated into `et` is shorter than the length of `s`

Comment: gives java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (3 ... 3) ends beyond length 2